# Convert JSON array of objects to string array using Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am using Angular 2 (latest version). I am trying to convert a JSON array i.e.

```
  jsonObject = [
    {"name": "Bill Gates"},
    {"name": "Max Payne"},
    {"name": "Trump"},
    {"name": "Obama"}
  ];
```

to a string array and store just the value in i.e

```
arrayList: [string] = [''];
```

array. I tried to use Stringify method but no luck.

Comment: String myString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject); did not work?

Comment: @GlenPierce No unfortunately it didnt work. I tried that before.

Comment: Please print the result of  JSON.stringify(jsonObject) and take a screen shot

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON array". There are just "JavaScript" arrays. There is nothing special here having to do with TypeScript or Angular. TypeScript is just a layer on top of JavaScript with type annotations and inference and checking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
names: string[] = jsonObject.map(person => person.name); 

// => ["Bill Gates", "Max Payne", "Trump", "Obama"]
```